# Print a rendered web page using java applet

Tags: java, printing, dialog, applet

I need to print the content of the rendered web page using Java applet (**with AND without print dialog**). I'm thinking of using Cobra library (http://lobobrowser.org/cobra/getting-started.jsp). The code given below is a bare minimum renderer which I believe will satisfy my requirement. How do I print the RENDERED content to the printer?

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import org.lobobrowser.html.gui.*;
    import org.lobobrowser.html.test.*;

    public class BareMinimumTest {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        HtmlPanel panel = new HtmlPanel();
        window.getContentPane().add(panel);
        window.setSize(600, 400);
        window.setVisible(true);
        new SimpleHtmlRendererContext(panel, new SimpleUserAgentContext())
.navigate("http://lobobrowser.org/browser/home.jsp");
      }
    }
```

Comment: just one silly question: Why not javascript and window.print() ?

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach  That is such a good question that I'm going to wait for the answer before considering a reply.

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach I need to customize the page settings (step 3) using the java applet and pop up the print dialog, so I can't use window.print()

Comment: A special Css for printig is not enough?

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach I've updated my question with more details to clarify the scenario. We are already using special CSS to format the page (print preview) and print it for 3a. Appreciate your input.

Comment: Well, with this more Info I am sure ... I have no idea :)

Comment: I think I'll be able to work out the rest if i could get some input on whether I need to use a html renderer (like Cobra renderer) to print html or link to the page (passed in as input using javascript to the applet) and if yes some code samples or link would be helpful.

Comment: @oraj did you succeeded ?